# How to find the most current field that is embedded in an array for X user in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I need to find a user with X `_id` and I need the most current `weightTracker.date` usually it will be the last one.

I've tried `db.user.find({_id:userid}, {weightTracker:1}).sort({"weightTracker.date":-1})`
With little success on ordering my results. But *most important* that always returns all the results and **I am only interested in the most current one**.

How Could I get the most recent object in `weightTracker` given the object's `date` in user X?

**User**

```
_id
weightTracker[{ manyproperties:menyproperties, date:date}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text, not just a screenshot.

Comment: I can not copy paste from a `DOS` terminal

Comment: Sure you can -- just click on the app icon in upper left, select `Edit \ Mark`, then highlight the selection you want and hit `Enter` on your keyboard. It's copied to the clipboard.

Comment: You can't combine all of those operations with an array in MongoDB when doing a retrieval. You could store them sorted, or always keep the most recent value in a secondary location within the document: `currentWeight`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try aggregate method (for detailed examples, you can see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/)

```
db.user.aggregate( { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("52426846311fc102641ef332") } } , 
                   { $unwind: "$weightTracker"},  
                   {$group: { _id: null, maxDate: {$max: "$weightTracker" } } }  
                 )
```